# Why does a wireguard VPN require forwarding for all networks?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

I have a wireguard peer (`server`), and two clients (`clientA` & `clientB`). They have the IP addresses `fd16:17:18::1`, `fd16:17:18::2`, & `fd16:17:18::3` respectively on the `wg0` interface.

When all of the wireguard connections are up, I can only ping `server` (i.e. `fd16:17:18::1`) from either of the client machines, and I can ping both client machines (i.e. `fd16:17:18::2`, & `fd16:17:18::3`) from `server`.

If I enable IPv6 forwarding for the `wg0` interface (with the sysctl configuration `net.ipv6.conf.wg0.forwarding=1`), nothing changes. Also enabling it for `eth0`, `default` or any combination of individual interfaces doesn't do anything.

However, if I enable forwarding for `all` interfaces, I can suddenly ping any machine from any other.

Why is it necessary to enable `forwarding` for `all`, instead of just `wg0`?

Comment: We have a veth-based lxc container networking configuration that behaves much the same way; my *guess* is that there is an internal interface object that we can't see (and so doesn't show up in sysctl -a) that gets forwarding enabled when we enable "all".  I enable all, then disable it individually for all interfaces except the "right" one (wg0 in your case), forwarding continues to work.  In my case, there's a veth that gets moved into the container namespace, but enabling forwarding in the container doesn't help.

Comment: Related, and at least a partial answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348533/is-net-ipv6-conf-all-forwarding-1-equivalent-to-enabling-forwarding-for-all-indi?rq=1

Comment: The above indicates that this behavior is policy: ipv6.all.forwarding=1 causes router behavior, and =0 causes host behavior.  IPv4 expertise does not map well onto IPv6!